# Why is AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION).build() not responding?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION).build() is waiting something?

I am using Amazon S3 and put many files to S3 every day by using this code.

```
AmazonS3 s3 = null;
s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION).build();
try {
    s3.putObject(bucket_name, key_name, new File(file_path));
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}
```

At one time, it works fine.
But AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION).build()
is not responding sometimes suddenly.

If I wait for a day or so, it works again.

This is a stack trace when
AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION).build()
is not responding.

Do you have any idea?

```
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(java.base@11.0.12/Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(java.base@11.0.12/ClassLoader.java:2442)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(java.base@11.0.12/ClassLoader.java:2498)
        - locked <0x000000070c9cf5c8> (a java.util.HashSet)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(java.base@11.0.12/ClassLoader.java:2694)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(java.base@11.0.12/ClassLoader.java:2648)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(java.base@11.0.12/Runtime.java:830)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(java.base@11.0.12/System.java:1873)
        at sun.security.ec.SunEC$1.run(jdk.crypto.ec@11.0.12/SunEC.java:63)
        at sun.security.ec.SunEC$1.run(jdk.crypto.ec@11.0.12/SunEC.java:61)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@11.0.12/Native Method)
        at sun.security.ec.SunEC.<clinit>(jdk.crypto.ec@11.0.12/SunEC.java:61)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(java.base@11.0.12/Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.base@11.0.12/NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.base@11.0.12/DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.base@11.0.12/Constructor.java:490)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(java.base@11.0.12/ServiceLoader.java:780)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(java.base@11.0.12/ServiceLoader.java:722)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(java.base@11.0.12/ServiceLoader.java:1395)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$ProviderLoader.load(java.base@11.0.12/ProviderConfig.java:340)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(java.base@11.0.12/ProviderConfig.java:248)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(java.base@11.0.12/ProviderConfig.java:242)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@11.0.12/Native Method)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(java.base@11.0.12/ProviderConfig.java:242)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(java.base@11.0.12/ProviderConfig.java:222)
        - locked <0x000000070cde52d0> (a sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(java.base@11.0.12/ProviderList.java:266)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getService(java.base@11.0.12/ProviderList.java:379)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(java.base@11.0.12/GetInstance.java:157)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(java.base@11.0.12/SSLContext.java:168)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkSSLContext.getPreferredSSLContext(SdkSSLContext.java:32)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:91)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:65)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:58)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:50)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:38)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:315)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:299)
        at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:172)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:638)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:35)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:32)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:64)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:28)
        at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old AWS SDK. Best practice is to update to [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html).

Here is the Java V2 code to use to place an object into an Amazon S3 bucket. You can find many other examples in [Github](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/s3).

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.s3_object_upload.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.s3_object_upload.import]

/**
 * To run this AWS code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your AWS credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class PutObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "  <bucketName> <objectKey> <objectPath> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "  bucketName - the Amazon S3 bucket to upload an object into.\n" +
                "  objectKey - the object to upload (for example, book.pdf).\n" +
                "  objectPath - the path where the file is located (for example, C:/AWS/book2.pdf). \n\n" ;

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName =args[0];
        String objectKey = args[1];
        String objectPath = args[2];
        System.out.println("Putting object " + objectKey +" into bucket "+bucketName);
        System.out.println("  in bucket: " + bucketName);

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        String result = putS3Object(s3, bucketName, objectKey, objectPath);
        System.out.println("Tag information: "+result);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.s3_object_upload.main]
    public static String putS3Object(S3Client s3,
                                     String bucketName,
                                     String objectKey,
                                     String objectPath) {

        try {

            Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
            metadata.put("x-amz-meta-myVal", "test");

            PutObjectRequest putOb = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(objectKey)
                    .metadata(metadata)
                    .build();

            PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(putOb,
                    RequestBody.fromBytes(getObjectFile(objectPath)));

           return response.eTag();

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }

    // Return a byte array
    private static byte[] getObjectFile(String filePath) {

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        byte[] bytesArray = null;

        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return bytesArray;
    }
    // snippet-end:[s3.java2.s3_object_upload.main]
}
```

Comment: yes, i am using aws-java-sdk 1.11, but i do not think this is a reason of my issue.

Comment: As I stated - the AWS V2 is considered best practice over V1.  I  have never seen such issues with V2.